# what is btree Pivot tuple format

Tags: postgresql

```
/*
 * Notes on B-Tree tuple format, and key and non-key attributes:
 *
 * INCLUDE B-Tree indexes have non-key attributes.  These are extra
 * attributes that may be returned by index-only scans, but do not influence
 * the order of items in the index (formally, non-key attributes are not
 * considered to be part of the key space).  Non-key attributes are only
 * present in leaf index tuples whose item pointers actually point to heap
 * tuples (non-pivot tuples).  _bt_check_natts() enforces the rules
 * described here.
 *
 * Non-pivot tuple format (plain/non-posting variant):
 *
 *  t_tid | t_info | key values | INCLUDE columns, if any
 *
 * t_tid points to the heap TID, which is a tiebreaker key column as of
 * BTREE_VERSION 4.
 *
 * Non-pivot tuples complement pivot tuples, which only have key columns.
 * The sole purpose of pivot tuples is to represent how the key space is
 * separated.  In general, any B-Tree index that has more than one level
 * (i.e. any index that does not just consist of a metapage and a single
 * leaf root page) must have some number of pivot tuples, since pivot
 * tuples are used for traversing the tree.  Suffix truncation can omit
 * trailing key columns when a new pivot is formed, which makes minus
 * infinity their logical value.  Since BTREE_VERSION 4 indexes treat heap
 * TID as a trailing key column that ensures that all index tuples are
 * physically unique, it is necessary to represent heap TID as a trailing
 * key column in pivot tuples, though very often this can be truncated
 * away, just like any other key column. (Actually, the heap TID is
 * omitted rather than truncated, since its representation is different to
 * the non-pivot representation.)
 *
 * Pivot tuple format:
 *
 *  t_tid | t_info | key values | [heap TID]
 *
 * We store the number of columns present inside pivot tuples by abusing
 * their t_tid offset field, since pivot tuples never need to store a real
 * offset (pivot tuples generally store a downlink in t_tid, though).  The
 * offset field only stores the number of columns/attributes when the
 * INDEX_ALT_TID_MASK bit is set, which doesn't count the trailing heap
 * TID column sometimes stored in pivot tuples -- that's represented by
 * the presence of BT_PIVOT_HEAP_TID_ATTR.  The INDEX_ALT_TID_MASK bit in
 * t_info is always set on BTREE_VERSION 4 pivot tuples, since
 * BTreeTupleIsPivot() must work reliably on heapkeyspace versions.
 *
 * In version 2 or version 3 (!heapkeyspace) indexes, INDEX_ALT_TID_MASK
 * might not be set in pivot tuples.  BTreeTupleIsPivot() won't work
 * reliably as a result.  The number of columns stored is implicitly the
 * same as the number of columns in the index, just like any non-pivot
 * tuple. (The number of columns stored should not vary, since suffix
 * truncation of key columns is unsafe within any !heapkeyspace index.)
 *
 * The 12 least significant bits from t_tid's offset number are used to
 * represent the number of key columns within a pivot tuple.  This leaves 4
 * status bits (BT_STATUS_OFFSET_MASK bits), which are shared by all tuples
 * that have the INDEX_ALT_TID_MASK bit set (set in t_info) to store basic
 * tuple metadata.  BTreeTupleIsPivot() and BTreeTupleIsPosting() use the
 * BT_STATUS_OFFSET_MASK bits.
 *
 * Sometimes non-pivot tuples also use a representation that repurposes
 * t_tid to store metadata rather than a TID.  PostgreSQL v13 introduced a
 * new non-pivot tuple format to support deduplication: posting list
 * tuples.  Deduplication merges together multiple equal non-pivot tuples
 * into a logically equivalent, space efficient representation.  A posting
 * list is an array of ItemPointerData elements.  Non-pivot tuples are
 * merged together to form posting list tuples lazily, at the point where
 * we'd otherwise have to split a leaf page.
 *
 * Posting tuple format (alternative non-pivot tuple representation):
 *
 *  t_tid | t_info | key values | posting list (TID array)
 *
 * Posting list tuples are recognized as such by having the
 * INDEX_ALT_TID_MASK status bit set in t_info and the BT_IS_POSTING status
 * bit set in t_tid's offset number.  These flags redefine the content of
 * the posting tuple's t_tid to store the location of the posting list
 * (instead of a block number), as well as the total number of heap TIDs
 * present in the tuple (instead of a real offset number).
 *
 * The 12 least significant bits from t_tid's offset number are used to
 * represent the number of heap TIDs present in the tuple, leaving 4 status
 * bits (the BT_STATUS_OFFSET_MASK bits).  Like any non-pivot tuple, the
 * number of columns stored is always implicitly the total number in the
 * index (in practice there can never be non-key columns stored, since
 * deduplication is not supported with INCLUDE indexes).
 */
```

quote:

```
 * Pivot tuple format:
 *
 *  t_tid | t_info | key values | [heap TID]
```

I can understand not-pivot tuple format. I don't understand pivot tuple format.
is the same non-unique btree key, one key, multiple heap page ctid match the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions like this, always turn to the appropriate [README file](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/nbtree/README;h=52e646c7f759a5d9cfdc32b86f6aff8460891e12;hb=HEAD#l31) first:

> Lehman and Yao talk about alternating "separator" keys and downlinks in
> internal pages rather than tuples or records.  We use the term "pivot"
> tuple to refer to tuples which don't point to heap tuples, that are used
> only for tree navigation.  All tuples on non-leaf pages and high keys on
> leaf pages are pivot tuples.  Since pivot tuples are only used to represent
> which part of the key space belongs on each page, they can have attribute
> values copied from non-pivot tuples that were deleted and killed by VACUUM
> some time ago.  A pivot tuple may contain a "separator" key and downlink,
> just a separator key (i.e. the downlink value is implicitly undefined), or
> just a downlink (i.e. all attributes are truncated away).

So a pivot tuple is an entry in a b-tree index that does not point to a table row.